# C++ : Error while deducing types for templated function

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to play around with type deduction in templates in c++. I am experimenting with type deduction for array arguments, with the following code:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t func(T (&)[N]) {
    return N;
}
```

This will simply return the length of the input array, Like So:

```
char arr[] = "abc";
cout << func(arr) << endl; // would print 3.
```

But when I modify the code of `func` to have an argument name, all hell is breaking loose!

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t func(T (&)[N] arr) {
    return N;
}
```

The main error I am getting seems to be this : Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E1097   unknown attribute "no_init_all" ProjectName C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\winnt.h  7597

Any Idea on what this issue is? and how to resolve it?

Clearly I don't need to declare the name for the parameter since I don't need to use it in this function, but just wondering why this error is popping up!

Comment: Use `T(& arr)[N]`

Comment: `"abc"` is actually a `char[4]`, it has a `\0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax would be

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t func(T (&arr)[N]);
```

You might use alias to have more natural syntax:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
using CArray = T[N];

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t func(CArray<T, N>& arr);
```